# Does antlr4 memoize tokens?

Tags: caching, antlr, antlr4

Let's say I have the following expression alternation:

```
    expr
      : expr BitwiseAnd expr
      | expr BitwiseXor expr
   // ...
      ;
```

Just for arguments sake, let's say that the `expr` on the left-hand-side turns out to be 1MB. Will antlr be able to 'save' that expression so it doesn't have to start-from-zero on each alternation, or how far does it have to backtrack when it fails to match on an alternation?

Just

Comment: Hard to say in this example, because it's a snippet of a grammar, but likely there is zero backtracking. AdaptivePredict() will read ahead and determine which alt to take in `expr` (1st or 2nd or 3rd ...). There is some backtracking, but it tries to avoid it.

Comment: The prediction engine creates kind of a memoized structure (ATN configs) for a taken path and reuses those when the same path has to be taken again (same lookahead steps), for a given input symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR will recognize the 1st `expr` and then if it doesn't find a `BitwiseAnd`, it will look for a `BitwiseXor` to try to match the second alternative.  It won't backtrack all the way to trying to recognize the 1st `expr` again.  It's not exactly memoization, but you get the same benefit (arguably even better).

You may find it useful to have ANTLR generate the ATN for your grammar. Use the `-atn` option when running the `antlr4` command, this will generate *.dot files for each of your rules (both Lexer and Parser).  You can then use `graphViz` to render them to svg, pdf, etc.  They may look a bit intimidating at first glance, but just take a moment with them and you'll get a LOT of insight into how ANTLR goes about parsing your input.

The second place to look is the generated parser code.  It too is much more understandable than you might expect (especially if reading it with the ATN graph handy).